# Contenteditable issue

Tags: jquery, html, webkit, contenteditable

In this: http://jsfiddle.net/bLHVh/4/ I have a contenteditable div, and whenever you type in it, it replaces 'a' with 'b', just as a simple example (it will do useful stuff later, of course). It works fine until you hit enter, then the div loses focus after every keystroke. Why is this?

Comment: which browser? does nothing but inserting the typed text in firefox 5

Comment: Chrome 14 dev. I'll try in other browsers

Comment: It also doesn't work right in safari 5.1, so must be a webkit thing.

Comment: In firefox 5, it let's you enter text just fine, but it doesn't replace the a's with b's like it should.

Comment: remeber it is html5 and it is not supported to 100% even in the alpha builds of the browsers

Comment: So there's no way to fix this issue? I only need it to work in webkit, no other browser matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#area").bind('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Surely that is going to stop the ability to make a new line?

Comment: Although, I was able to modify that to insert a newline and move the cursor down. Still some glitches, but better than before.